# Java Interface Design - Helper Methods

Tags: java, software-design

I have an interface like so

```
public interface Manager {
    public void manage();
}
```

Now, all `Manager`s will need to load work to manage, however, I have mixed feelings about adding `public void loadWork()` to the interface...

On one hand, all `Manager`s will do this, but on the other hand, users of a `Manager` class will not need to know about `loadWork()`.

**Question**:  Is it bad practice to add "helper" or "setup" type methods to an interface?

Comment: What stops you to add them to other interface?

Comment: You mean have a separate interface, say `WorkLoader` that does this, and each `Manager` has a `WorkLoader`?  If so, it seems like that only shifts the problem.  How do I enforce `Manager`s to have a `WorkLoader`?  Or should I?

Comment: You don't have to. When you implement `Manager` interface, you can optionally implement `WorkLoader` interface too.

Comment: Ah, good point! Composition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not always a bad idea to add "setup" methods in an interface. For example, Java EE has an interface called [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) that is purely meant to make setup and shut down.
It's even sometimes acceptable to make interfaces with methods you should actually never directly call such as the [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) or the [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interface.

Being said that, it seems is that you want to force your developers to implement a loadWork() method in Manager but you also want to hide it from the class' users. 
As you say, one option is adding the method in the interface but this way the method will be accessible (which you don't want). If you don't want the method to have visibility I see two options:

1. Make the class **Manager** an abstract class and add a **loadWork()** protected method.
2. Create an interface called **LoadWorker** with a method **loadWork()**. Then create an abstract class **AbstractManager** that implements **Manager** and has as a private/protected **LoadWorker** field. This way, even though **loadWork()** is public, it's not accessible from **AbstractManager**'s users as it is called through a protected/private field (**LoadWorker**).

At the end it comes to a balance between overengineering and good design. It's up to you to take the decision following the specific needs. Nevertheless, there is no 'perfect solution'.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I was considering something along the lines of the second, but was hoping to avoid using an abstract class. I guess I will try this approach, though.  
Also, great examples with `Callable`/`Runnable`.